# subcategorization in neural networks

Tags: neural-network

I have to build a neural network for text classification that should tell the category and subcategory it belongs to. For example, I have to classify an input(text) to {'Poultry','Wild'} and if it is poultry(First Stage Classification), then we have to classify whether it is a cow or duck or any other element in the subset mentioned here (subset = {‘Cows’,‘Ducks’, ‘Geese’, ‘Goats’, ‘Hens’}).
So, how to implement this in a Neural Network ? How to map the output of the first level of classification to the input of second neural network ?